# Django make migrations error

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to make migrations for an app that I created in Django. My files are organised as follows:

```
wisdompets/db.sqlite3
wisdompets/manage.py
wisdompets/adoptions/__init__.py
wisdompets/adoptions/admin.py
wisdompets/adoptions/apps.py
wisdompets/adoptions/models.py
wisdompets/adoptions/tests.py
wisdompets/adoptions/views.py
wisdompets/adoptions/migrations/__init__.py
wisdompets/wisdompets/__init__.py
wisdompets/wisdompets/settings.py
wisdompets/wisdompets/urls.py
wisdompets/wisdompets/wsgi.py
wisdompets/wisdompets/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
wisdompets/wisdompets/__pycache__/settings.cpython-36.pyc
wisdompets/wisdompets/__pycache__/urls.cpython-36.pyc
wisdompets/wisdompets/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
```

Initially I tried to make migrations by typing in the following into the terminal: ('adoptions' is the app name)

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations adoptions
```

But it's saying that the app could not be found. So I went to `settings.py` and added the app under `Installed_APPS` by typing in the following: `'adoptions.apps.AdoptionsConfig'`.
Now when I go back to the terminal and type in the same commands as before, this is what came up:

[image]

Anyone has idea how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't post code or images as pictures. But you have a typo; it should be `CharField`.

Comment: Ahhh I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your stacktrace it says you're using:

```
name = models.Charfield()
```

but it should be

```
name = models.CharField()
```

with a capital F.
That's why it hasn't found the attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't believe it's just a simple typo!

Comment: Glad to help :)